# Existe alguma diferença prática em utilizar a tag <source> sozinha ou acompanhada da tag principal de mídia como <audio> por exemplos?

Tags: html, html5, html-tags

Então... Existe uma diferença prática de quando utilizar com ou sem uma tag pai? por exemplo:

Usar a Tag sozinha:
`<audio src="/audio/music.mp3" controls></audio>`
Ou com uma tag filha pra executar a solicitação?
Exemplo:

```
<audio controls>
        <source src="/audio/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tag `<source>` não pode ser usada sozinha (sem a tag pai), ela é uma tag para ser usada como elementos filhos das tags `<video>`, `<audio>` e `<picture>` e nos exemplos que apresentou não existem diferenças no resultado.

O objetivo da tag `<source>` é fornecer diferentes recursos em formatos diferentes,  claro que você pode usar de forma indevida, mostrando 2 vídeos visualmente diferentes, mas isso cabe a você como desenvolvedor decidir o que vai apresentar.

A tag pode ser usada para controlar qual recurso vai ser exibido baseado na resolução ou outro formato da visibilidade, isso através do atributo `media=""`, que usa o mesmo formato das *Media queries* do CSS, como já deve saber, existem *Media queries* especificas de navegadores ou sistemas operacionais, mas isso é outra história, então baseado na resolução você pode apresentar um recurso diferente, no entanto isso é [só suportado/válido quando o elemento pai for um `<picture>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element):

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="resolucao-baixa.png" media="(max-width: 800px)">
   <source srcset="resolucao-media.png" media="(max-width: 1300px)">
   <img src="resolucao-alta.png" alt="foo bar">
</picture>
```

> Note que o endereço de imagens em `<picture>` devem ser definidos com
> o atributo `srcset` nos elementos `<source>`.

No exemplo a tag `<img>` serve de *fallback* para navegadores sem suporte e para acaso a resolução não "case" com os elementos `<source>` (existe outro meio de tratar resoluções de imagem baseado em tamanhos, mas isso irei citar em outra resposta, talvez já tenha no site).

Em resumo, os atributos usados pelo elemento `<source>`:

- `src=""` usado quando o elemento pai for [`<video>` ou `<audio>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#media-element)
- `srcset=""` usado quando o elemento pai for `<picture>`
- `sizes=""` usado quando o elemento pai for `<picture>`
- `media=""` usado quando o elemento pai for `<picture>`

Voltando ao `<audio>`, nem todo sistema operacional ou navegador suporta todos formatos de áudios, então o uso de `<source>` resolve esse caso, como exemplo:

```
<audio>
  <source src="foobar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="foobar.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <p>Seu navegador não suporta áudio</p>
</audio>
```

O mesmo pode ser feito com vídeo, inclusive com vídeo é mais comum. Apesar de certos navegadores serem afirmados tendo suporte, muitos na verdade alguns dependem dos codecs instalados no sistema operacional (o que o usuário pode fazer, mas não é garantido, justamente por depender disso).

Para ver sobre os formatos de áudio e vídeo suportados por diferentes navegadores recomendo que use o **caniuse**:

- [Can I use audio format](https://caniuse.com/?search=audio%20format)
- [Can I use video format](https://caniuse.com/?search=video%20format)

Note que além do `type=""` é usado para ajudar o navegador a identificar se o formato é suportado, antes de fazer o "download", você também pode (ou talvez precise) definir o parâmetro `; codecs=` junto ao *MIME-type* dentro do atributo `type=""`, [pois pode ser necessário para o navegador saber exatamente como o recurso é codificado](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6381):

Áudio Vorbis sozinho em um **"container" Ogg**

```
<source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis">
```

Áudio Speex sozinho em um **"container" Ogg**

```
<source src="audio.spx" type="audio/ogg; codecs=speex">
```

Áudio FLAC sozinho em um **"container" Ogg**

```
<source src="audio.oga" type="audio/ogg; codecs=flac">
```

> Apesar dos exemplos das extensões, elas não definem o conteúdo, são
> apenas extensões e são usadas para ajudar o sistema operacional a
> "adivinhar" o conteúdo, ou para **servidores web** fornecerem o
> `Content-Type` adequado em respostas HTTP.

Em resumo, o uso da tag `<source>` depende de como você, o desenvolvedor, configura e fornece os recursos, você é livre para escrever "errado" é claro, ou de forma redundante, mas é claro que aprender o básico e aplicar de forma correta será o que irá fazer isso funcionar para o usuário.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta bem completa.